# Spanning R3 question (Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, to span R3, you need to have to be able to reduce a matrix as such

`[1   0   0 | x1]
 [0   1   0 | x2]
 [0   0   1 | x3]`

Correct? Now, what if you have a matrix like this

`[1   0   0   0 | x1]
 [0   1   0   0 | x2]
 [0   0   1   0 | x3]
 [0   0   0   1 | x4]`

or

`[1   0   0   0 | x1]
 [0   1   0   0 | x2]
 [0   0   1   0 | x3]
 [0   0   0   0 | x4]`

or

`[1   0 | x1]
 [0   1 | x2]`

Do any of those span? Or can a matrix only span R3 if it is exactly 3x3 and it RREF to the matrix I put in first?

Comment: The second and last sets definitely don't span $\Bbb R^3$.  For the third, you'd have to tell me how you define $\Bbb R^3$.  Is it the set of all $3\times 1$ matrices?  Then no, it doesn't span.  Is it the $3$-dimensional vector space over the reals defined up to isomorphism?  Then yes, it does span.

Comment: Also, here's how to format your questions a little nicer.  To get $\Bbb R^3$, type `$\Bbb R^3$`.  To get $\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0 & x_1 \\ 0 & 1 & x_2 \end{array}\right]$, type `$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0 & x_1 \\ 0 & 1 & x_2 \end{array}\right]$`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. As I will probably have more matrice questions in the future, this will help me out!  And as for which definition we use, I will have to ask my professor on that but I think I get the general idea.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries.  For more info on how to format your questions (and maybe eventually answers) see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column vectors of an $m\times n$  matrix span a *subspace* of $K^m$, and this subspace has dimension equal to the row-rank of the matrix, which you find by row-reduction.

Also note the row-rank is the same as the column-rank, which means a matrix and its transpose have the same rank.